# using jpg encoder in javascript mobile

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I am using the jpg.js encoder I found via Google. There is a copyright '2011 notmasteryet'.

Cannot find the author so cannot quote them.

I have a web site and I am using the canvas control.

The canvas control is populated using this jpg encoder.

I acquire an image as byte array from my server and I use that encoder to 'copy' and 'putdata' to that canvas control.

When I use a browser via desktop it works.
When I use it on a browser via Android it does not.

The canvas control is supported on this device.

The error I get is that 'TypeError: Result of expression 'JpegImage' [undefined] is not a constructor.

I have placed the calling code in windows.onload and document.ready events still no joy.

this is my latest attempt:

```
<!--create jpeg image-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmrplayback;

    function createJPEGEncoder() {
        try {
            c1 = document.getElementById("canvaslive1x4");
            ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
            d1 = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, 360, 288);
            c1.setAttribute('width', '360');
            c1.setAttribute('height', '288');
            j1 = new JpegImage();
            alert('ok');
            j1.onload = function () {
                try {
                    j1.copyToImageData(d1);
                    ctx1.putImageData(d1, 0, 0);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    document.getElementById("divMode").innerHTML = 'err#2: ' + err;
                }
            };
        }
        catch (err) {
            document.getElementById("divMode").innerHTML = 'err#3: ' + err;
            alert(err);
        }
        alert('done');
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        createJPEGEncoder();
    }
</script>
```

the javascript code for the obejct creation 'JpegImage' is a lot of code to post here and was not created by myself.  But I stress it works on desktop browsers...

Comment: What's the line of the exception and what browser have you used?

Comment: Hi,  thanks for trying to help me. The error occurs on j1= new JpegImage() line. The browser on my Android has this Useragent: mozilla/5.0 (linux; u; android 2.2.1; en-gb; htc wildfire build/frg83d) applewebkit/533.1 (khtml, like gecko) version/4.0 mobile safari/533.1

Comment: Hi Again, I managed to drill down a bit more - sorry I should have been more comprehensive. The error occurs when declaring this :  new Int32Array

Comment: Ah, I see. It's that Android's stock browser version 2.2.1 [doesn't support typed arrrays](http://caniuse.com/#feat=typedarrays). In short, that library may not support the Android browser before Android 4, or any browser that has no typed arrays.

Comment: I guess I need a new phone :) Thanks for that link..